# Aggregate initialization

Tags: c++

If I have a struct and I initialize it like so:

```
#include <memory>

struct MyHandle
{
        std::shared_ptr<int> handle_;
};

int main()
{
        MyHandle m{std::make_shared<int>(42)};
}
```

Is the fact that aggregate initialization of MyHandle occurs so  **no constructor** is used to initialize object of type MyHandle?

Comment: Guys, I've edited my question slightly to make myself more clear. Basically, what I'm asking is: will there, at any point, any of MyHandle constructors (in this case the one generated by compiler) be executed, or is MyHandle initialized without constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct. Aggregate initialisation is only allowed for classes with no user-provided constructors, and (in the words of the standard, C++11 8.5.1/2), "each member is copy-initialised from the corresponding initialiser-clause". So no constructor for `MyHandle` is used, only a copy, move or conversion constructor for each member of class type.

The implicit default constructor, which default-initialises each member, is used for default and value initialisation; but it can't be used for aggregate initialisation since each member can only be initialised once.

Comment: Hi Mike, very interesting and informing answer. Your answer contradicts (I don't take any sides, I just want to know what really happens) answer given in comment, by user1600151. Would you mind and comment on it?

Comment: @smallB I mean, an automatically-generated constructor still exists and is still called in cases where you create a MyHandle object in other ways, but when you initialize it with an initializer list, the constructor is bypassed.

Answer (score 4):

MyHandle is not a POD, because a POD can't contain non-POD members (and shared_ptr is not a POD). shared_ptr's constructor is definitely called when constructing a MyHandle object.

Comment: But `MyHandle` is an aggregate and thus aggregate initialization is allowed, which is the reason why the OP is able to initialize it with braces.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently std::shared_ptr is not POD, you could use [std::is_pod](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) to check POD type:

```
std::is_pod<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value
```

should return 0